# How to call function with correct argument in jQuery-resizable object which is creating in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

I've couple of resizable objects and I'd like to trigger function 'changeS()' when I stop resizing the object.
Function changeS() should takes as first argument the name of the object for which it's called.
I mean:
when I stop resizing object "#resizable0" then should be called changeS(#resizable0,new_size - old_size), 
when I stop resizing object "#resizable1" then should be called changeS(#resizable1,new_size - old_size), etc.

There is everything OK when I just set in code this method for every object i have, but I'd like to do it in loop for(), because there will be much more objects, and then I have a problem:

```
var old_size=0;
var new_size=0;
var x,i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
x = "#resizable"+i;
var $res = $(x);

$res.resizable({
    grid: 22, minHeight:22, handles: 's',
    start: function(event,ui) {
        old_size = ui.originalSize.height;
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        new_size = ui.size.height;

        if(new_size!=old_size)
            changeS($res,new_size - old_size);
    }
});
}
```

I don't know how to correctly pass a name of object as an argument of the function.
When function changeS() is executed it's always called with the same name - name of the last created object ("#resizable5" - in this case).

My question is:
How do I make for each object the function changeS() was called with the corresponding argument(name of this object)?

Thanks, popKonr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're creating in the loop are *closures*. They keep an *enduring reference* to the variables they close over, *not* a copy of the value as of when the function is defined. And so all of them see the last value you assign to `$res`, not the value during "their" loop.

The usual way to solve this is to use a factory function, something like this:

```
var x,i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    x = "#resizable"+i;
    var $res = $(x);

    makeResizeable($res);
}

function makeResizeable($thisres) {
    var old_size = 0,
        new_size = 0;

    $thisres.resizable({
        grid: 22, minHeight:22, handles: 's',
        start: function(event,ui) {
            old_size = ui.originalSize.height;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {
            new_size = ui.size.height;

            if(new_size!=old_size)
                changeS($thisres,new_size - old_size);
        }
    });
}
```

Note how we now use `$thisres`, the argument passed into the factory function `makeResizeable`, rather than `$res`, since the argument baked into the functions we create within `makeResizeable` isn't changed. Also note I've moved `new_size` and `old_size` into that factory function as well. The event handlers will close over that data, and so each pair of them will get their own private copies of those variables.

[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), but there are a few fundamental things about them people tend to misunderstand. Once you've got those down, though, you'll be in good shape.

Comment: Thanks for the help and patient explanations.
Of course, I noticed what was happening, but this is my first steps and did not even know how such a function is called, which is why I could not find a solution to my problem.

Thank you again. The solution that you provided seems to work great.
Oh, and thanks for the link to an excellent description of the closures!

Comment: @popKonr: No worries, glad that helped! Always happy to help someone get off on the right track with closures.